# flutter firestore and androidx compatibilty issue

Tags: flutter, gradle, androidx, github-actions

Please kindly help!

I am running an automated build using GitHub actions to build an app bundle and release it to the play store.
It fails at the build release stage. Below is my action file:

HERE IS MY PLUGINS :

```
version: 99.99.99+99

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  intro_views_flutter: "^2.8.1"
  fluttertoast: ^7.0.2
  toast: ^0.1.5
  intent: ^1.4.0
  flutter_tts: 1.0.0
  flutter_paystack: "1.0.4+1"
  shared_preferences: "^0.4.2"
  url_launcher: ^5.4.2
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.20
  # firebase_auth: ^0.18.1+1

  # Add the dependency for the Firebase Core Flutter SDK
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.0+5
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.3
  google_sign_in:
    ^4.5.3
```

THE GITHUB ACTION RUNNER

```
- run: flutter pub get
      # - run: flutter test
      - run: flutter build apk --release --split-per-abi
      - run: flutter build appbundle
      - name: Create a Release in GitHub
        uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1
        with:
          artifacts: "build/app/outputs/apk/release/*.apk,build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab"
          token: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}
          tag: ${{ steps.version.outputs.content }}
          commit: ${{ github.sha }}
      - name: Upload app bundle
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: appbundle
          path: build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab
  release:
    name: Release app to internal track
    needs: [build]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Get appbundle from artifacts
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: appbundle
      - name: Release app to internal track
        uses: r0adkll/upload-google-play@v1
        with:
          serviceAccountJsonPlainText: ${{ secrets.PLAYSTORE_ACCOUNT_KEY }}
          packageName: com.philencripted.earlyread
          releaseFile: app-release.aab
          track: internal
          whatsNewDirectory: distribution/whatsnew
```

`Run flutter build apk --release --split-per-abi`

AND AM GETTING THE BELOW ERROR

`Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...`

````
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings




warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings




warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.







Note: /opt/hostedtoolcache/flutter/1.22.2-stable/x64/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.11/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /opt/hostedtoolcache/flutter/1.22.2-stable/x64/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.11/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 warnings

warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release



warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

3 warnings


warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.


3 warnings

warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.


3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.


3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.



Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Note: /opt/hostedtoolcache/flutter/1.22.2-stable/x64/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-0.3.24/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/webviewflutter/FlutterWebView.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

3 warnings

warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release


warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

3 warnings

warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.



3 warnings


Calling mockable JAR artifact transform to create file: /home/runner/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/cf27c79d9a1ca383a5de54e0c43a32fe/android.jar with input /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar

Calling mockable JAR artifact transform to create file: /home/runner/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/8f3797ea408b2bbea5e5c1abe74922af/android.jar with input /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar

Calling mockable JAR artifact transform to create file: /home/runner/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/ffcaf9949b48e1d1efd7816ff2a6c939/android.jar with input /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/platforms/android-29/android.jar

Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 989KB to 939KB: Removed 5%

Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 989KB to 939KB: Removed 5%

Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 989KB to 939KB: Removed 5%

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences:verifyReleaseResources'.






> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

   > Android resource linking failed

     /home/runner/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/3aaf6e5219b7f981ec263df919098c6f/core-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.



     /home/runner/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/3aaf6e5219b7f981ec263df919098c6f/core-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.





* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org



BUILD FAILED in 5m 45s

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          346.6s (!)
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                     
The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.```
````